# Why Minutes of Business Hours are not Calculated in Apex Trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger

I have design a Apex Trigger Code:

```
trigger BusinessHrs on Customer__c (before insert, before update) {

Long Diff1;
Long Diff2;

for(Customer__c c1: trigger.new)
{BusinessHours stdBusinessHours = [select id from businesshours where id = '01mi0000000aAVI'];
DateTime d1 = DateTime.newInstance(1997, 1, 31, 7, 8, 16);
DateTime d2 = DateTime.newInstance(1997, 1, 31, 7, 8, 16);

d1=c1.Startdate__c;
d2=c1.EndDate__c;

Diff1=BusinessHours.diff('01mi0000000aAVI',d1, d2) ;
c1.Business_Hour1__c=(Diff1/(1*60*60*1000));

DateTime d3=DateTime.newInstanceGmt((d1.dateGmt()), (d1.timeGmt()) );
DateTime d4=DateTime.newInstanceGmt((d2.dateGmt() ), (d2.timeGmt() ) );

Diff2=BusinessHours.diff('01mi0000000aAVI',d1, d2) ;
c1.Business_Hour2__c=(Diff2/(1*60*60*1000));


} 
}
}
```

In Both Business_Hour1__c,Business_Hour2__c the number field(decimal 2 places) have no decimal value... Is something wrong in :
Diff2=BusinessHours.diff('01mi0000000aAVI',d1, d2) ;
c1.Business_Hour2__c=(Diff2/(1*60*60*1000));

Thanks in advanced... First question posted ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
trigger BusinessHrs on Customer__c (before insert, before update) {

Long Diff1;
Long Diff2;

Decimal de1;
Decimal de2;

for(Customer__c c1: trigger.new)
{BusinessHours stdBusinessHours = [select id from businesshours where id = '01mi0000000aAVI'];
//if(!String.isBlank((c1.EndDate__c).format())  && !String.isBlank((c1.Startdate__c).format()))
if((c1.EndDate__c != null) && (c1.Startdate__c != null))
 { 
DateTime d1 = DateTime.newInstance(1997, 1, 31, 7, 8, 16);
DateTime d2 = DateTime.newInstance(1997, 1, 31, 7, 8, 16);

d1=c1.Startdate__c;
d2=c1.EndDate__c;

Diff1=BusinessHours.diff('01mi0000000aAVI',d1, d2) ;
c1.Business_Hour1__c=(Diff1/(1*60*60*1000));

DateTime d3=DateTime.newInstanceGmt((d1.dateGmt()), (d1.timeGmt()) );
DateTime d4=DateTime.newInstanceGmt((d2.dateGmt() ), (d2.timeGmt() ) );

Diff2=BusinessHours.diff('01mi0000000aAVI',d1, d2) ;     
De1=BusinessHours.diff('01mi0000000aAVI',d1, d2) ;
de1=((De1/(1*60*60*1000))-(diff2/(1*60*60*1000)));

De2=((de1/100)*60);
c1.Business_Hour2__c=((Diff2/(1*60*60*1000))+de2);

} 

}


}
```

This is the apex code which calculate business hours for given record id of Business Hrs .

Comment: OH,, its calculated in Business_Hour2__c field .

Answer (score 0):

Because Long does not include a decimal point:

```
A 64-bit number that does not include a decimal point. Longs have a minimum value of -263 and a maximum value of 263-1. Use this datatype when you need a range of values wider than those provided by Integer. For example:
Long l = 2147483648L;
```

Try using final value of Decimal instead of long. And remember that the value of the diff is returned in milliseconds so you will have to **divide the number returned in the long by the appropriate value of milliseconds to get the decimal value you are seeking**

The below example executed in dev console will show you what I am talking about:

```
Long l = 100;
system.debug(logginglevel.error,l/300);
Decimal d = 100;
system.debug(logginglevel.error,d/300);
```

The debug for l/300 = 0;
The debug for d/300 = 0.333

Comment: De1=BusinessHours.diff('01mi0000000aAVI',d1, d2) ;
De2=(De1/(1*60*60*1000));
c1.Business_Hour2__c=de2;

First of all thank you for reply.... and i found your help useful ... now by using this I am able to return decimal value... But they are a little off:

d1=23/12/2014 3:30 PM
d2=23/12/2014 5:36 PM
business hrs returned= 2.10

IT should have return 2.06 any idea why??

Comment: I got the problem 6 sec is 10% of 60 sec so its returning 10 which is 10% of 100. so i think its decimal equivalent of seconds.. This pattern is for 20 sec is 0.33 and so on.... NO IDEA HOW TO SOLVE THIS

Comment: @RachitJain Then you will have to parse out the minutes and seconds. Take the .10 and multiple 60 by it to get your minutes. End up with 2 min 6 Sec. Please mark as answer so the question does not keep getting automatically bumped to the top